# Does Go have library which opens paletted png of 2 bit color-depth?

Tags: go, image-processing

How do you read a palette-based PNG image with Go?

For an image in Python I can simply do:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.png')
pix = im.load()
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        print(pix[i, j])
```

Using Go:

```
    f, err := os.Open("image.png")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    pal, ok := cfg.ColorModel.(color.Palette) // ok is true
    if ok {
        for i := range pal {
            cr, cg, cb, ca := pal[i].RGBA()
            fmt.Printf("pal[%3d] = %5d,%5d,%5d,%5d\n", i, cr, cg, cb, ca)
        }
    }

    img, err := png.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // Fails here!!
    }

    for y := img.Bounds().Min.Y; y < img.Bounds().Max.Y; y++ {
        for x := img.Bounds().Min.X; x < img.Bounds().Max.X; x++ {
            log.Println("img.At(x, y):", img.At(x, y))
        }
        fmt.Print("\n")
    }
```

It'll go to throws "png: invalid format: not a PNG file" when decoding.

If I use the `file` command on Mac shell it says:

```
image.png: PNG image data, 100 x 100, 2-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

And VsCode render the image just fine.

I tried it both on an image created from Adobe Illustrator and one generated from the below code. Both run into the same error:

```
func createPNG() {
    // Create a new image with the desired dimensions
    img := image.NewPaletted(image.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), color.Palette{
        color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 255}, // Red
        color.RGBA{0, 255, 0, 255}, // Green
        color.RGBA{0, 0, 255, 255}, // Blue
    })

    // Set the pixel colors in the image
    for x := 0; x < 100; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < 100; y++ {
            switch {
            case x < 50 && y < 50:
                img.SetColorIndex(x, y, 0) // Set the pixel at (x, y) to red
            case x >= 50 && y < 50:
                img.SetColorIndex(x, y, 1) // Set the pixel at (x, y) to green
            case x < 50 && y >= 50:
                img.SetColorIndex(x, y, 2) // Set the pixel at (x, y) to blue
            default:
                img.SetColorIndex(x, y, 3) // Set the pixel at (x, y) to transparent
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a new file to save the PNG image
    file, err := os.Create("image.png")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Encode the image as a PNG and save it to the file
    err = png.Encode(file, img)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case seems to be not the format of the image, but rather the way you use the image file.

I assume you first pass it to `image.DecodeConfig()` (the code doesn't show it but `cfg` must have been initialized) and later to `image.Decode()`.

The problem is that after the first call your file has an offset but the second call assumes that it is reading from the beginning of the file.

You can solve this by rewinding the file after reading the configuration:

> file.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)

Comment: I don't see `DecodeConfig` in any of the posted code, and it doesn't look like the question was edited.

Comment: I don't see it either. Looks like some of the lines were omitted. I assume `cfg` was initialized using `DecodeConfig()`.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it clear.

Comment: Holy molly (or whatever is more modern these days) you're right! Detective dev.bmax. I wouldn't have suspected that I'd have to move the offset back to the beginning! Thank you so much!